# MongoDB c# driver - Submit multiple different find queries at the same time

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to be able to submit multiple FIND queries to my MongoDB with a single connection.  Similar functionality to the BulkWrite method, but I need something like a BulkFind.  I understand that the Find method works similarly, however, it has one difference in that it doesn't append multiple queries together, it just runs a single query with 1 set of filters.

Currently, I have two non-working solutions to my issue.  The first uses the Find method:

```
FilterDefinition<ItemBase> allFilters;
List<FilterDefinition<ItemBase>> combineFilter = new List<FilterDefinition<ItemBase>>();

foreach (ItemSearch item in items)
{
     var filter = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemTier == item.ItemTier);
     var filter2 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemRarity.ToLower() == item.ItemRarity.ToLower());
     var filter3 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemType.ToLower() == item.ItemType.ToLower());
     var filter4 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemSlotType.ToLower() == item.ItemSlotType.ToLower());
     combineFilter.Add(Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.And(filter, filter2, filter3, filter4));
}

allFilters = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Or(combineFilter);

returnList = _items.Find(allFilters).ToList();

return returnList;
```

The second non-working solution uses the Aggregate().Match() functionality:

```
FilterDefinition<ItemBase> allFilters;
List<FilterDefinition<ItemBase>> combineFilter = new List<FilterDefinition<ItemBase>>();

foreach (ItemSearch item in items)
{
     var filter = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemTier == item.ItemTier);
     var filter2 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemRarity.ToLower() == item.ItemRarity.ToLower());
     var filter3 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemType.ToLower() == item.ItemType.ToLower());
     var filter4 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemSlotType.ToLower() == item.ItemSlotType.ToLower());
     combineFilter.Add(Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.And(filter, filter2, filter3, filter4));
}

allFilters = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Or(combineFilter);

returnList = _items.Aggregate().Match(combineFilter).ToList();

return returnList;
```

However, the problem with both of these solutions is that it only returns a single instance of the result.  My goal is that it can find the same document more than once and return it multiple times, if needed.  I am looking for something that appends a bunch of different FIND queries together and sends them all to the database to be run at the same time, however, I haven't found any such functionality, yet.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing can be achieved by using the aggregation pipeline with a [facet stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/), This allows you to process multiple aggregation pipelines (in your case `$match`) and output each of their results in one query.

This can be built up like the following in C# using partly the fluent aggregation API and also creating a facet stage for each search.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var items = db.GetCollection<ItemBase>("items");

var itemSearches = new List<ItemSearch>();

var facets = new List<AggregateFacet<ItemBase, ItemBase>>();

for (var i = 0; i < itemSearches.Count; i++)
{
    var item = itemSearches[i];
    var filter1 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemTier == item.ItemTier);
    var filter2 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemRarity == item.ItemRarity);
    var filter3 = Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemType == item.ItemType);
    var filter4 =
        Builders<ItemBase>.Filter.Where(x => x.ItemSlotType == item.ItemSlotType);

    FilterDefinition<ItemBase> filter = filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4;

    var facet = AggregateFacet.Create($"Search{i}", PipelineDefinition<ItemBase, ItemBase>.Create(
        new IPipelineStageDefinition[]
        {
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(filter)
        }
    ));

    facets.Add(facet);
}


var results = await items.Aggregate()
    .Facet(facets)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach (var aggregateFacetResult in result.Facets)
    {
        var facetResults = aggregateFacetResult.Output<ItemBase>();

        // facetResults containers each of the filters
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I think your solution would have worked perfectly, however, I moved in a slightly different direction.  I ended up grabbing all the "viable" documents from my database using the Find function I detailed in my OP, then, once they were back in code, I ran through them with my original list to produce duplicate ItemBase items where needed.  This seemed to be the more efficient way of handling it and also reduced the response size.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in the server to issue multiple find queries in one command.

If you are looking to decrease query latency, I suggest moving the application closer to the database (or adding another application closer to the database that would aggregate query results).